# logo image not appearing in title bar of browser's tab

Tags: html, css, image

I want to display logo image in the title bar like others, but my code isn't working, PLEASE HELP!!

I have applied to following code but not getting results-

```
<title> <img src="logo.png"> Company name </title>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to add a favicon is:

```
<link rel="icon" href="favicon.jpg" />
```

You DO NOT add it to the title bar.

Then to add text to the tab name:

```
<title>Company Name</title>
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: yes, I will accept it surely, kindly wait for 7 minutes before I can accept any answer

Comment: @OmChaudhary Thanks! No problem, I can wait!